Kubernetes readiness probe failing for next.js app
Kubernetes readiness check keeps failing for NextJS app (On GCP).
Without the timeoutSeconds: 10 I get:

Readiness probe failed: Get "http://10.60.2.69:3000/api/healthcheck": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

So I assume the connection to the pod is successful.
When I include the timeout (after waiting a while) I am getting:

Timeout waiting for pod to become healthy in at least one of the NEG(s): [k8s1-8e09c...]. Marking condition "cloud.google.com/load-balancer-neg-ready" to True.

client-deployment.yaml
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: client-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: client
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: client
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: client
          image: nodejsclient
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /api/healthcheck
              port: 3000
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 10
            failureThreshold: 3
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: client
  ports:
    - name: client
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000

pages/api/healthchek.ts

export default function HealthPage (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse){
   res.status(200).json({status: 'OK'})
}

UPDATE:
curl to the pod get a 200 response

UPDATE2:
I tried different configurations for the readinessProbe, including deleting it, NULL value, root path, different flags/timeouts and command instead of HTTP.
Additionally deleted and created ingress.
Everything had the same result. I did notice that I am also getting "Unable to determine the pod's node name", but I don't know if that is relevant.


You don't demonstrate that HealthPage is both implemented and accessible on /API/healthcheck with nodejsclient[:latest]. Please update your question showing that this container image responds on the path /api/healthcheck with success (200). You could (!) drop the readinessProbe, kubectl port-forward deployment/client-deployment 3000:3000 and then curl -get http://localhost:3000/api/healthcheck.

@DazWilkin question updated

I'm unable to repro the issue using a repro of your image and a non-GKE Kubernetes cluster. This make it difficult to help. You may want to try Google Cloud support.

The issue was in the nextjs app itself and not the deployment configuration.
I disabled a redirect in the middleware.ts and now it is working.
The nextjs app worked without errors + responded with 200 on /api/healthcheck, so I am still not sure why that caused an issue but the face stays the problem was resolved.
